# Django custom permissions unable to call in decorator as i passed in params

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-permissions

I want to apply django permissions on viewsets and I create a decorator for this but its not working. I just want to call the permission class in decorator as passed in argument.

views.py

'''

```
class MapViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   serializer_class = MapSerializer

    @permission_decorator(permission_class=MapPermission)
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Map.objects.all()
```

'''

utils.py

'''

```
   METHODS = {'GET': 'view_permission',
       'PATCH': 'add_permission',
       'POST': 'add_permission',
       'PUT': 'add_permission',
       'DELETE': 'delete_permission'}


   def check_user_permission(permission, user, tag):
       # logic here
       return True/False



   class CustomBasePermissions(permissions.BasePermission):
       @abstractmethod
       def has_permission(self, request, view):
       pass


   class PermissionError(APIException):
       status_code = status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
       default_detail = {'message': "You Don't have required permission"}



   class MapPermission(CustomBasePermissions):
       def has_permission(self, request, view):
           if request.role == "owner":
              return True
           else:
              permission = METHODS.get(request.method)
              return check_user_permission(permission, request.user, 'map')
```

'''

decorators.py

'''

```
def permission_decorator(permission_class):

     assert permission_class is not None, (
      "@permission_decorator() missing required argument: 'permission_class'"
          )

    def decorator(func):
       func.permission_classes = permission_class
       return func

    return decorator
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

Please apply the permissions in permission classes of your viewset

```
class MapViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   serializer_class = MapSerializer
   permission_classes = [MapPermission]
```

This will automatically caters all request types you will perform through this viewset.